# find values from drop down in single listings with beautiful soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and have a car website with dropdown. How can I choose a car brand (for example BMW) in the dropdown menu and then click to see all cars with this brand? Is this even possible with `Beautifulsoup` or would I need `Selenium`?

The website is this https://www.leasingmarkt.ch/listing. I managed to get the data_values (numbers) that need to be entered for each car brand but I don't know how to enter them into the website and then click?

```
for x in soup.find_all("div", class_ = "dropdown manufacturer-dropdown"):
    for car in x.find_all('li'):  
        try:
            cars_id[car.find("span").text] = car.get('data-value')
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

I think it would work by just changing the url so that the number of the car brand is in the link. But how would it work to choose and then click (if at all possible with `BeautifulSoup`)?

Comment: if you need to click then use Selenium's functions instead of `Beautifulsoup`. You can't "click" in `Beautifulsoup` - you can only get URL and load new HTML with `requests`/`urllib`. But if page uses JavaScript to load new page then you will need `Selenium` without `Beautifulsoup`

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to update page. When you select element then it runs JavaScritp which runs url like `https://www.leasingmarkt.ch/lmrpc/listing-ajax-update?lmrpc=1.0&query=%22v%3D2%26ids%3D%26sort%3Dpopularity%26takeoverContract%3D0%26newContract%3D1%26manufacturer%3D13 ...` and get results as JSON and replace it in HTML. In this url you can see `manufacturer .. 13` where `13` is value from dropdown list for `BMW`.  You could use this url with `requests` to get page but it can be easier to do it with Selenium.

Comment: how exactly did you get this url?

Comment: I used `DevTools` in `Firefox/Chrome` (tab `Network`, filter `XHR`) to see all requests send by JavaScript from browser to server.

Comment: I mean the code to get the above url? Would it work with Selenium?

Comment: I get this URL manually - without using code - and when I have URL then I don't neeed code to get it because now I could create code which generate URL(s). But Selenium doesn't need this URL. Using `Selenium` you need code like in some answer below - and this is why I said it can be simpler with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium, it should be simple:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)  # Add this at least, if it won't work add explicit wait
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id("manufacturer")
dropdown.click()
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".select.searchable.btn.manufacturer-dropdown>.selection").send_keys("bmw")
```

Use waits https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

If implicit wait does not work for this case, use explicit wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#manufacturer")))
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id("manufacturer")
dropdown.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".select.searchable.btn.manufacturer-dropdown>.selection")))
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".select.searchable.btn.manufacturer-dropdown>.selection")
input_field.clear()
input_field.send_keys("bmw")
```

**Try 2:**
For manufacturer field, try few locators: `#manufacturer> .select>.selection` or `#manufacturer> .select`

Also try using `#manufacturer> .select` for input field if a given one won't work.

Also, for the first element try to replace: `element_to_be_clickable` with `visibility_of_element_located`

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me an error `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`. Do you know why?

Comment: On which locator?

Comment: I still get the error. `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.114)`. What do you mean by locator?

Comment: If input_field.clear() won't work, use input_field.click() and then input your search text

Comment: thanks so much. Now `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#manufacturer")))` gives `TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231125/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-corianne1234).